# Using select on ActiveRecord throws "no route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Something really weird is happening and I am not sure how to fix it.

I have two classes on my DB. Projects and timelogs.

On my index method for the Projects controller, I am listing a list of projects and I also want to list the last date where any log was entered for that project.

When I run the code below, I get the following error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects", :id=>#<Project id: nil, name: "Project A", user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

If I comment the "select" line and uncomment the line above (with Project.all), everything works perfectly.

Any idea why this could be happening?

```
def index
    #@projects = Project.all

    @projects = Project.select("julianday(Date('now')) - julianday(log.timeofevent) as diff, *").joins("left outer join timelogs log on projects.id = log.project_id").group("projects.id").order("log.timeofevent asc")

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @projects }
    end
end
```

Comment: I suspect that error occurs in your view, not the controller. Add the first couple of lines from the stack trace and the matching lines from the view, it that's the case, please.

Comment: Show your view and your routes. That's probably where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is being caused because in the view your code is attempting to create links that will show each project.  This might look like this:

```
link_to 'Show', project
```

Or maybe like this:

```
link_to 'Show', project_path(project)
```

Something in your query is returning rows with no `projects.id` (as you can see in the error, the `id` is `nil`).  I suspect your error is the `group` function, that needs an aggregate function so it definitely seems wrong, I'm not sure immediately why it would be causing a null project.id.  Did you mean to use `order`?

### Added

I just realized that you're probably using it to get rid of duplicates.  So anyway, back to where everyone else was then I think - more info needed :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for the answers. You were right on. Indeed, the issue was when the view tried to generate a link and it was missing things like the ID.

I thought that this would work:

```
@projects = Project.select("julianday(Date('now')) - julianday(log.timeofevent) as diff, *").joins("left outer join timelogs log on projects.id = log.project_id").group("projects.id").order("log.timeofevent asc")
```

But, apparently "(star)" alone won't work. I had to replace it to "projects.(star)"

So, the resulting fixed code (works fine) is:

```
@projects = Project.select("julianday(Date('now')) - julianday(log.timeofevent) as diff, projects.*").joins("left outer join timelogs log on projects.id = log.project_id").group("projects.id").order("log.timeofevent asc")
```